# CSS transition makes left border disappear

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've set up a landing page for practice, where an h1 + a paragraph slide in, and a "Read More" button slowly appears. I've also set it up so that when you hover over the "Read More" button, it rotates 180 degrees on the y axis. However, my problem is that the left border vanishes when I hover over. Here's what it looks like when this happens:
[image]
The text is flipped because I rotated it on the Y axis, but the left (well, actually right because it's flipped) border vanishes. Any ideas on why?
Here's my code:

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: #12475f;
        color: white;
        line-height: 1.6;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
    
    #showcase {
        height: 300px;
    }
    
    #showcase h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        position: relative;
        animation-name: heading;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes heading {
        0% {top: -50px;}
        100% {top: 200px}
    }
    
    #content {
        position: relative;
        animation-name: content;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes content {
        0% {right: 100%;}
        100% {right: 0;}
    }
    
    .btn {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
        border: white 1px solid;
        margin-top: 40px;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0;
        animation-name: btn;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-delay: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        transition-property: transform;
        transition-duration: 1s;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    
    @keyframes btn {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1;}
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landing.css">
        <title>Landing Page</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header id="showcase">
            <h1>Welcome To My Site</h1>
        </header>
        <div id="content" class="container">
            <p>(pause) You thought wrong, dude. (He shoots and Marty falls to the ground.) (Tannen laughs and walks over to where Marty lays motionless on the ground. Doc watches Tannen then looks down at Marty in disbelief.) Ahh, thank ya. (Tannen stops just in front of Marty. He points his gun down at Marty meaning to finish him off. Suddenly Marty kicks the gun out of Tannen's hand. He stands up to face Tannen. Tannen throws a punch and nearly breaks his hand. Marty lifts his poncho to reveal the stove door that he put on as a bullet-proof vest. He saw the same thing in the Clint Eastwood movie that Biff was watching in the other 1985 time line.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm new to web design, so the solution is probably obvious. However, I just can't figure out why this is happening. Please Help!
Thanks,
Lyfe

Comment: Can you make a JS Fiddle for this? Your CSS looks okay, so this makes me wonder if it is a Chrome bug (I found a similar border bug once).

Comment: @JoshBradley I got the same result, and here is a jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/px9bk5z1/

Comment: Does it happen at every zoom level and/or resolution? I've occasionally noticed weird graphical glitchiness / artifacts in chrome with CSS transforms.

Comment: So I was seeing the same issue, but in the middle of testing, the issue resolved itself... Not sure what to think, but it seemed to be an issue with sub-pixel rendering with `transform`. If you still see the issue, try defining the width explicitly with `.btn { width: 5rem }` and it should work okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem that occurs when "hovering" is the css line at the class btn:

```
    .btn { 
        padding: 1rem 2rem; 
    }
```

I also noticed that It seems okay with your code snippet until I tested it in https://codepen.io. The **border-left** you are referring to be the problem seems to be **border-bottom** to us.

I made some changes prior to your code:

You can visit this [pen](https://codepen.io/vehsoriano/pen/gKGZMW) and play over the code.

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: #12475f;
        color: white;
        line-height: 1.6;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .container {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
    
    #showcase {
        height: 300px;
    }
    
    #showcase h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        line-height: 1.3;
        position: relative;
        animation-name: heading;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes heading {
        0% {top: -50px;}
        100% {top: 200px}
    }
    
    #content {
        position: relative;
        animation-name: content;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes content {
        0% {right: 100%;}
        100% {right: 0;}
    }

    span {
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
    }

    .btn {
        width: auto;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 60px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        /* padding: 1rem 2rem; */            
        border: white 1px solid;
        margin-top: 40px;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0;
        animation-name: btn;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-delay: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        transition-property: transform;
        transition-duration: 1s;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    
    @keyframes btn {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1;}
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="landing.css">
        <title>Landing Page</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header id="showcase">
            <h1>Welcome To My Site</h1>
        </header>
        <div id="content" class="container">
            <p>(pause) You thought wrong, dude. (He shoots and Marty falls to the ground.) (Tannen laughs and walks over to where Marty lays motionless on the ground. Doc watches Tannen then looks down at Marty in disbelief.) Ahh, thank ya. (Tannen stops just in front of Marty. He points his gun down at Marty meaning to finish him off. Suddenly Marty kicks the gun out of Tannen's hand. He stands up to face Tannen. Tannen throws a punch and nearly breaks his hand. Marty lifts his poncho to reveal the stove door that he put on as a bullet-proof vest. He saw the same thing in the Clint Eastwood movie that Biff was watching in the other 1985 time line.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn">
           <span>Read More</span>
        </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code stops the border from disappearing:

```
.btn {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not at home, so I'll test this when I am and if it works, I'll mark it as correct. However, can you please explain to me why this code fixes it?